# Does Amazon AppSync support Amazon QLDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, amazon-qldb

Could anyone let me know if Amazon AppSync supports integration with Amazon QLDB and point me to the right direction?

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 1):

The data sources supported by default include Amazon DynamoDB tables, RDS databases, Amazon Elasticsearch domains, AWS Lambda functions, and third-party HTTP endpoints.

But you can utilize AWS Lambda to integrate with alternative data sources like Amazon QLDB.[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-aws-appsync-neptune-elasticache/) article gives an explanation.